# 404 pages in wordpress after hosting

Tags: wordpress, apache

I have hosted my website on an amazon ec2 instance and it seems that all the pages except the home page are not working

example.

> The requested URL /about/ was not found on this server.

Where I select in the permalink setting/Custom Structure `'/index.php/%postname%/'` it works fine, by the `index.php` is always part of the url.

The installation if Apache is fresh as well as the one for the wordpress. in my local host, everything is working fineWordpress

This is the `.htaccess`

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

is this an Apache problem or is it wordpress? and how can I solve it?

Comment: What's your configuration for the directive `AllowOverride` in your Apache configuration?

Comment: its `None`. I have changed it to `All` but it did not work